# No sounds control > External Monitor?

Tags: keyboard, audio, mac-mini

Mac Mini M1 is connected to an LG UltraWide 49WL95C over UCB-C,

The Volume shortcut keys weren't working, and when I look in System Preferences there is no Volume control ...

Any workaround? (rather than turning the volume manually up/down on the back of the monitor all the time)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, [MonitorControl](https://github.com/MonitorControl/MonitorControl/releases) seems to do the trick